# How to implement an efficient real-time search with large datasets in a web application?

Tags: javascript, web, search, dataset, real-time

I'm working on a web application that requires an efficient real-time search feature. My application has a dataset with over a million records, and I need to provide the user with quick and accurate search results as they type. The dataset will also be updated regularly, so the solution needs to be able to handle updates without impacting the search performance.

I've considered using simple client-side filtering with tools like Fuse.js, but I'm concerned about performance issues with such a large dataset. On the other hand, server-side solutions like Elasticsearch seem like overkill and could introduce latency due to the network round-trip.

What would be the most efficient and scalable approach to implement real-time search in a web application with a large and dynamic dataset? Ideally, I'm looking for a solution that can provide a balance between client-side and server-side processing while minimizing the impact on overall performance.

Here's an example of how my data is structured:

```
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "John Doe",
    "email": "john.doe@example.com",
    "city": "New York"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Jane Smith",
    "email": "jane.smith@example.com",
    "city": "San Francisco"
  },
  // ... more records
]
```

Comment: And what code have you tried to get a result and why is that not working for you?